# Button trigger when they press Enter in the Page in MVC view without using Jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a Modal in MVC view that has a button which call java script to post to controller. How I can make the Button trigger when they press Enter in the Page.
I am not sure where in View I can call the JavaScript Function.

Please no Jquery. I have to use only use Javascript for this purpose.

This is My View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("forgotPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div>
                <div>Email Address</div>
                <div><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" id="email" class="forgot-password-textbox"></div>
                <div><label id="Message" class="forgot-password-error-message"></label></div>
                <div><input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn-reset-password" onclick="resetPasswordHandler()" class="orange-button forgot-password-button"></div>
            </div>
        }
```

and this is Js method:

```
function resetPasswordHandler() {
    //Post Data to Controller
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I only use Javascript`? You are already using jQuery Ajax.

Comment: @Win for this purpose, I only allow to use java script.

Comment: If jQuery is already there, use it. Either you only use vanilla JavaScript for everything or go ahead and use jQuery for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call *resetPasswordHandler* function when enter key is pressed.

```
document.onkeydown = function () {
    if (window.event.keyCode == '13') {
        resetPasswordHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is technically the only thing that will work globally without having to focus the form, first. However, it should be noted that an event handler on something like `document` will be *very* inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `onsubmit` function on the form (instead of `onclick` on the button)
2. Return false from the function to prevent the form submission
3. Change your button to `type='submit'`

---

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("forgotPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return resetPasswordHandler()" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div>
                <div>Email Address</div>
                <div><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" id="email" class="forgot-password-textbox"></div>
                <div><label id="Message" class="forgot-password-error-message"></label></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn-reset-password" class="orange-button forgot-password-button"></div>
            </div>
        }
```

---

```
function resetPasswordHandler() {
    var postResult = null;
    var data = {
        Email: document.getElementById('email').value
    };
    var path = "/forgotPassword";

    var errorMessage = document.getElementById('Message');

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: path,
        data: data,

        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            postResult = $.parseJSON(result);
            if (postResult.status == "success") {
                $('#forgot').hide();
                $('#forgot-thank-you').show();
            }
            else {
                errorMessage.innerHTML = postResult.message;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "An error occured";
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I have added the code but do nothing when I press Enter.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify something - you say "no jQuery", but in your code you are using jQuery in your attempt ($.ajax). Are you ALSO looking for a way to send ajax data without using jQuery? It's a little confusing.

Comment: The form has to be in focus first, i.e. some field or control within the form must have focus.